# GCP Cloud Build can't connect to GCS bucket with file during build stage in dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

This is the dockerfile that I'm using:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your credentials file
COPY project-key.json /app/project-key.json

# Set the environment variable for the credentials
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /app/project-key.json

# Download the file from GCS using the gsutil command
RUN gsutil cp gs://project-id/file.txt /app/file.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

It works when building from Cloud Shell, but not when running from Cloud Build. I get the following error:

> ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have
> storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
> Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not
> exist). The command '/bin/sh -c gsutil cp
> gs://project-id/file.txt /app/file.txt' returned a
> non-zero code: 1

Where are the credentials/roles missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you run your Docker step, do this:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ['cp', 'gs://mybucket/my_file', 'my_file']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach to interface with GCStorage running the Cloud Build pipeline.

the cloud build yaml would one have one step and remember to add this param
--network value cloudbuild :

```
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_APP:$_TAG', '.', '--network=cloudbuild']
```

The docker file would have 2 Parent Images(python:3.9, gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil) so it is enable to interface amoung python and gcs at the same env on runtime.

```
FROM python:3.9 as python
```

Run all commands to install python libs etc

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil as gcs
```

Run all commands to interface with cloud storage

In my scenario i created a zip with all python files and lib dependencies, then i send it to gcs. (the zip file is used with dataproc)